# Spring Boot Application generated by Spring initializr gives error while running on eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have create a project in spring with few dependencies like web, thymleaf etc. I have imported it in eclipse and ran it , I am getting the following error output. Kindly guide me how to fix this.

```
2018-07-03 12:41:39.165  INFO 34800 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-03 12:41:39.212  INFO 34800 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse 4.4/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse 4.4/jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Eclipse 4.4/jre/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\ThinPrint\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Box\Box Edit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Informix\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk7\lib;C:\Program Files\Informix\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\GSK7_64\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\GSK7_64\lib64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QTP\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\TkDiff;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Users\xxxx\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Windows\system32;;.]
2018-07-03 12:41:39.584 ERROR 34800 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.StaticResourceJars.toFile(StaticResourceJars.java:75) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.StaticResourceJars.addUrl(StaticResourceJars.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.StaticResourceJars.getUrlsFrom(StaticResourceJars.java:58) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.StaticResourceJars.getUrls(StaticResourceJars.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.AbstractServletWebServerFactory.getUrlsOfJarsWithMetaInfResources(AbstractServletWebServerFactory.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.access$300(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:96) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory$StaticResourceConfigurer.lifecycleEvent(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:675) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-07-03 12:41:39.584 ERROR 34800 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.walmart.ZFAMRestServices.ZfamRestServicesApplication.main(ZfamRestServicesApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-07-03 12:41:39.599  INFO 34800 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-03 12:41:39.599  WARN 34800 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-07-03 12:41:39.677  INFO 34800 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-03 12:41:39.693 ERROR 34800 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.walmart.ZFAMRestServices.ZfamRestServicesApplication.main(ZfamRestServicesApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

The POM file was generated in spring initializr and it was not modified

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Post your pom file and looks like incompatible Servlet API. And format the post with more content.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component` -> seems like a malformed URL somewhere in your property files?

Comment: I am not modifying any properties but I am getting this error.

Comment: Use tomcat8 server

Comment: It is already tomcat 8 only

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. Please clean your .m2 or .gradle directory and build the application again. This should be able to solve the issue. This had worked for me.